# panda DataFrame.value_counts().plot().bar() and DataFrame.value_counts().cumsum().plot() not using the same axis

Tags: python, pandas, cumsum

I am trying to draw a frequency bar plot and a cumulative "ogive" in the same plot. If I draw them separately both are shown OK, but when shown in the same figure, the cumulative graphic is shown shifted. Below the code used.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Correctas': [4,6,5,4,7,2,8,3,5,6,9,6,6,7,5,5,8,10,4,8,3,6,9,5,11,5,12,7,7,5,4,6]});

df['Correctas'].value_counts(sort = False).plot.bar();
df['Correctas'].value_counts(sort = False).cumsum().plot();

plt.show()
```

The frequency data is

```
2      1
3      3
4      7
5     14
6     20
7     24
8     27
9     29
10    30
11    31
12    32
```

So the cumulative shall start from 2 and it starts from 4 on x axis.

[image showing the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlQp9.png)

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with bar chart plotting categorical x-axis.  Here is a quick fix:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Correctas': [4,6,5,4,7,2,8,3,5,6,9,6,6,7,5,5,8,10,4,8,3,6,9,5,11,5,12,7,7,5,4,6]});

df_counts = df['Correctas'].value_counts(sort = False)
df_counts.index = df_counts.index.astype('str')

df_counts.plot.bar(alpha=.8);
df_counts.cumsum().plot(color='k', kind='line');

plt.show();
```

Output:

[image]